# Level cap in Blitzball?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I have been playing a lot of Blitzball since buying the new Remastered version and some of my characters are getting around upper 30's for levels...With this being said what is the max level in blitzball, if there is one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max level for Blitzball is level 99.  Your players can continue to gain experience until then.

There's a grainy image here:
[image: Hifurey Blitzball level 99]

Which comes from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHzv4qyowk8).  Word of warning, though, it's a pretty crappy video.  It does show at least this player at level 99, though.

Comment: As I thought. Can you show a picture or something of an example though?

Comment: Well, I could take a screenshot of my strategy guide, but it would be kind of crappy.

Comment: Anything to just see someone at lvl 99 would make me happy.

Comment: ......I want lvl 99 players now haha Thanks for the info Frank!